# No Launcher activity found

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, launcher

I can't find any problem but it keep giving me the error "No Launcher activity found!" and "The launch will only sync the application package on the device!"
can anyone solve this problem???

**This is my Maniest**

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.saikoro.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

            <activity
        android:name="com.example.saikoro.StartUp"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.saikoro.StartUp" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<activity>` element of the activity you want to launch through the icon on the app list must contain *both* of the following parts of the intent-filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
```

Your current manifest has an activity with category `LAUNCHER` and action `MAIN`, but in different activities. The one with the icon in the app list must have them both.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but I don't understand why.Please can you try to explain why?

Comment: Those are the category and action events that an Activity must register for so that Android knows it is the Activity you want launched on your icon click. I'm not sure what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<action android:name="com.example.saikoro.StartUp" />
```

with

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```